# Filter for max effective dating

Tags: sql, sql-server-2014

I have the below query that gets me EMPLID's that have at least two rows with `COVERAGE_ELECT = 'E'` and have Plan Type 49.

```
WITH Coverage_CTE (EMPLID, COVERAGE_ELECT)
 AS
  (
  SELECT EMPLID, COUNT(COVERAGE_ELECT) 
  FROM PS_SAVINGS_PLAN
  WHERE COVERAGE_ELECT = 'E'
  AND PLAN_TYPE = '49'
  GROUP BY EMPLID
  HAVING COUNT(COVERAGE_ELECT) > 1 
  )
, Emp_CTE (EMPLID)
AS
(
  select distinct EMPLID from Coverage_CTE
)
  SELECT SP.EMPLID, SP.PLAN_TYPE, SP.EFFDT, SP.COVERAGE_ELECT, SP.SAVINGS_COVRG, SP.FLAT_DED_AMT, SP.PCT_GROSS
  FROM PS_SAVINGS_PLAN as SP
  WHERE SP.EMPLID IN (Select EMPLID from Emp_CTE)
  AND SP.COVERAGE_ELECT = 'E'
  AND PLAN_TYPE = '49'
```

This seems to work fine, however I want to further filter down the results by only including rows where there isn't a row for the `EMPLID` with an effective date that is greater than the max `EFFDT` of the 'E' rows selected above that is **either** a 'W' or a 'T'.

The above query currently has rows for `EMPLID` 5423H (because this person you see has more than 1 `COVERAGE_ELECT = 'E'` rows (3)). However you see that this person has two rows with `COVERAGE_ELECT` equal to T and W with `EFFDT`'s greater than the effective date of the max `EFFDT` 'E' row (2018-10-01).

```
EMPLID      PLAN_TYPE    EFFDT         COVERAGE_ELECT
5423H       49           2013-01-01    W
5423H       49           2015-10-02    E
5423H       49           2015-10-09    T
5423H       49           2016-09-29    E
5423H       49           2018-10-01    E
5423H       49           2018-10-07    T
5423H       49           2018-11-14    W
```

So you see both scenarios in this example - 1. This EMPLID has a row with a 'T' that is greater than (2018-10-07) the max EFFDT 'E' row (2018-10-01) and 2. They have a row with 'W' that is greater than (2018-11-14) the max EFFDT 'E' row. If either of these scenarios are true then I do not want them to result in my query above. I'm looking to build this additional logic into the above query. I hope this makes sense..

Comment: . . Your question is really complicated and hard to follow.  It is more so because your original query is just not a good way to implement the logic.  I might suggest that you start with a new question asking how to re-implement the query that you do have.

Comment: Emp_CTE seems pointless.  Coverage_CTE is grouped by EMPLID so I believe DISTINCT is redundant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**all untested**
I would change your CTE to include the max effdt, add another CTE for max WT EFFDATE, then choose your favorite method for excluding one from the other.

LEFT JOIN and WHERE null:

```
;WITH Coverage_CTE (EMPLID, COVERAGE_ELECT, MAXEFFDT)
AS (
    SELECT EMPLID, COUNT(COVERAGE_ELECT), MAX(EFFDT) MAXEFFDT
    FROM PS_SAVINGS_PLAN
    WHERE COVERAGE_ELECT = 'E'
       AND PLAN_TYPE = '49'
    GROUP BY EMPLID
    HAVING COUNT(COVERAGE_ELECT) > 1 
)
, WT_Coverage_CTE (EMPLID, WTMAXEFFDT)
As (
   SELECT EMPLID, MAX(EFFDT) WTMAXEFFDT
   FROM PS_SAVINGS_PLAN
    WHERE COVERAGE_ELECT IN ('W', 'T')
       AND PLAN_TYPE = '49'
    GROUP BY EMPLID
)

SELECT SP.EMPLID, SP.PLAN_TYPE, SP.EFFDT, SP.COVERAGE_ELECT, 
SP.SAVINGS_COVRG, 
       SP.FLAT_DED_AMT, SP.PCT_GROSS
    FROM PS_SAVINGS_PLAN as SP
INNER JOIN Coverage_CTE CCTE on CCTE.EMPLID = SP.EMPLID
LEFT OUTER JOIN WT_Coverage_CTE WTCTE
   on WTCTE.EMPLID = CCTE.EMPLID
   and WTCTE.WTMAXEFFDT > CCTE.MAXEFFDT
WHERE SP.COVERAGE_ELECT = 'E'
   AND PLAN_TYPE = '49'
   AND WTCTE.EMPLID is null
```

NOT EXISTS:

```
;WITH Coverage_CTE (EMPLID, COVERAGE_ELECT, MAXEFFDT)
AS (
    SELECT EMPLID, COUNT(COVERAGE_ELECT), MAX(EFFDT) MAXEFFDT
    FROM PS_SAVINGS_PLAN
    WHERE COVERAGE_ELECT = 'E'
       AND PLAN_TYPE = '49'
    GROUP BY EMPLID
    HAVING COUNT(COVERAGE_ELECT) > 1 
)
, WT_Coverage_CTE (EMPLID, WTMAXEFFDT)
As (
   SELECT EMPLID, MAX(EFFDT) WTMAXEFFDT
   FROM PS_SAVINGS_PLAN
    WHERE COVERAGE_ELECT IN ('W', 'T')
       AND PLAN_TYPE = '49'
    GROUP BY EMPLID
)

SELECT SP.EMPLID, SP.PLAN_TYPE, SP.EFFDT, SP.COVERAGE_ELECT, SP.SAVINGS_COVRG, 
   SP.FLAT_DED_AMT, SP.PCT_GROSS
FROM PS_SAVINGS_PLAN as SP
INNER JOIN Coverage_CTE CCTE on CCTE.EMPLID = SP.EMPLID
WHERE SP.COVERAGE_ELECT = 'E'
   AND PLAN_TYPE = '49'
   AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT EMPLID
                   FROM WT_Coverage_CTE WTCTE
                   WHERE WTCTE.EMPLID = CCTE.EMPLID
                      AND WTCTE.WTMAXEFFDT > CCTE.MAXEFFDT
                   )
```

where not in:

```
;WITH Coverage_CTE (EMPLID, COVERAGE_ELECT, MAXEFFDT)
AS (
    SELECT EMPLID, COUNT(COVERAGE_ELECT), MAX(EFFDT) MAXEFFDT
    FROM PS_SAVINGS_PLAN
    WHERE COVERAGE_ELECT = 'E'
       AND PLAN_TYPE = '49'
    GROUP BY EMPLID
    HAVING COUNT(COVERAGE_ELECT) > 1 
)
, WT_Coverage_CTE (EMPLID, WTMAXEFFDT)
As (
   SELECT EMPLID, MAX(EFFDT) WTMAXEFFDT
   FROM PS_SAVINGS_PLAN
    WHERE COVERAGE_ELECT IN ('W', 'T')
       AND PLAN_TYPE = '49'
    GROUP BY EMPLID
)

SELECT SP.EMPLID, SP.PLAN_TYPE, SP.EFFDT, SP.COVERAGE_ELECT, SP.SAVINGS_COVRG, 
   SP.FLAT_DED_AMT, SP.PCT_GROSS
FROM PS_SAVINGS_PLAN as SP
INNER JOIN Coverage_CTE CCTE on CCTE.EMPLID = SP.EMPLID
WHERE SP.COVERAGE_ELECT = 'E'
   AND PLAN_TYPE = '49'
   AND CCTE.EMPLID NOT IN (SELECT EMPLID
                           FROM WT_Coverage_CTE WTCTE
                           WHERE WTCTE.EMPLID = CCTE.EMPLID
                           AND WTCTE.WTMAXEFFDT > CCTE.MAXEFFDT
                          )
```

data I used:

```
declare @PS_SAVINGS_PLAN table (emplid varchar(8), plan_type int,
                      effdt date, coverage_elect varchar(1))

insert into @ps_savings_plan
values
      ('5423H', 49, '2013-01-01', 'W'),
      ('5423H', 49, '2015-10-02', 'E'),
      ('5423H', 49, '2015-10-09', 'T'),
      ('5423H', 49, '2016-09-29', 'E'),
      ('5423H', 49, '2018-10-01', 'E'),
      ('5423H', 49, '2018-10-07', 'T'),
      ('5423n', 49, '2018-10-07', 'E'),
      ('5423n', 49, '2018-10-08', 'E'),
      ('5423H', 49, '2018-11-14', 'W')
```

Comment: Thank you! This works perfectly, and I appreciate you providing a few different methods.

Answer (score 2):

Based on your narration this can be answered based on simple *conditional aggregation*:

```
WITH Coverage_CTE AS
 (
   SELECT EMPLID 
     ,Count(CASE WHEN COVERAGE_ELECT IN ('E') THEN effdt end) AS cntE
     ,Max(CASE WHEN COVERAGE_ELECT IN ('T', 'W') THEN effdt end) AS maxT
     ,Max(CASE WHEN COVERAGE_ELECT IN ('E') THEN effdt end) AS maxE

   FROM @PS_SAVINGS_PLAN
   WHERE PLAN_TYPE = '49'
   GROUP BY EMPLID
 )
SELECT EMPLID FROM Coverage_CTE
WHERE 
   -- at least two rows with COVERAGE_ELECT = 'E'       
   cntE > 1

   -- where there isn't a row for the EMPLID with an effective date that is greater
   -- than the max EFFDT of the 'E' rows selected above that is either a 'W' or a 'T'
  AND (maxT < maxE OR maxT IS NULL)
```

Comment: Your query is picking up about 100 fewer rows then the other answer provided. Any thoughts?

Comment: Maybe `AND (maxT <= maxE OR maxT IS NULL)`